# Uploading a Mac app with Application Loader

Tags: objective-c, macos, loader

So I was trying to upload my app to the mac app store using application loader and I got to the step where I'm going to choose the file which is going to be uploaded which if I remember right is the .app file in a .zip? The problem is that it won't let me choose the .zip file.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should contact Apple for assistance with their App Store requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for the solution and found the recent information here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/OSXWorkflowGuide/DistributingApplications/DistributingApplications.html